# Remove quotes from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

When I call `JSON.stringify`, I get a JSON string like `[{"id":"001","name":"Mary"},{"id":"002","name":
"Tom"}]`. How can I make it so that it looks like this?

```
[
    {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
    {id: 29, name: "C#"},
    {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
    {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
    {id: 41, name: "C"},
    {id: 43, name: "C++"},
    {id: 47, name: "Java"}
]
```

Comment: what's the question? and what have you tried, and what hasn't worked so far?

Comment: I am not sure how Mary and Tom became Ruby, C#, Fortran, Visual Basic, C, C++, and Java.

Comment: Why are the two samples are different?

Comment: the value of name is not important,I just want to delete the ""

Comment: **There is no such thing** `String[]` in javascript...

Comment: I just want to change "id":"001","name":"Tom" to id:001,name="Tom"

Comment: because I want to use it,  $("#demo-input-local").tokenInput([
                {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
                {id: 29, name: "C#"},
                {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
                {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
                {id: 41, name: "C"},
                {id: 43, name: "C++"},
                {id: 47, name: "Java"}
            ]);

Comment: @user1658116: You know it works with or without the quotes, right?

Comment: For the solution to the question, see this thread:
Removing quotation marks in JSONObject: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952237/removing-quotation-marks-in-jsonobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952237/removing-quotation-marks-in-jsonobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so apparently you want to take out the quotes and indent it nicely? Then I would do that beforehand:

```
function indent(str) {
    return str.replace(/\n/g, '\n\t');
}

function toPrettyObject(obj) {
    var ajsoln = []; // Actual JavaScript Object Literal Notation

    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            ajsoln.push(indent(toPrettyObject(obj[i])));
        }

        return '[\n' + ajsoln.join(',\n') + '\n]';
    } else if(typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    } else {
        for(var x in obj) {
            ajsoln.push('\t' + (/^[a-zA-Z_\$][\w\$]+$/.test(x) ? x : JSON.stringify(x)) + ': ' + indent(toPrettyObject(obj[x])));
        }

        return '{\n' + ajsoln.join(',\n') + '\n}';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not JSON, standard JS objects where the IDs are strings and he wishes they were numbers.

Comment: I get my data through var json=JSON.stringify(value);

Comment: @MattGreer: What makes you say it's not JSON? (Anyway, if it's not... skip right to the second part.)

Comment: @minitech -- ah yup, it is in fact JSON. My bad. Nevermind :)

Comment: Reviver function would be useful here. `function(key, val) { return key === "id" ? +val : val; }`

Comment: If all you want is to pretty print the stringified output, you're doing too much work. `JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t");` And if you want to convert the IDs to numbers, add the above reviver in place of `null`.

Comment: @graystateiscoming: That doesn't take care of the quotes, and I'd rather not use some kind of messy regular expression. It's two tiny functions... not really too much work.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's the quotes around the object keys. I didn't pick up on that.