# Remove " " from search results

Tags: java, android

I have a stocks function in my application where users can search for stocks and see their prices. For some reason it displays " " around the stock name and the sock abbreviation (as shown in the image). I want to remove the quotation marks, but can't quite find what to change in the code.

[Stock Portfolio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL2VU.png)

```
EditText searchQueryEditText;
Button searchButton;
ProgressBar progressBar;

RecyclerView stocksRecyclerView;
MyAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

ArrayList<StockItem> stockItems;

public static ArrayList<String> stockItemsToSearch;

Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_market_info);

    stockItemsToSearch = new ArrayList<>();

    stockItems = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(stockItems);

    stocksRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.stockRecyclerView);
    searchQueryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQueryEditText);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    stocksRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    stocksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String searchQuery = searchQueryEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
            stockItemsToSearch.add(searchQuery);

            searchQueryEditText.setText("");

            hideKeyboard();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            loadStockData(generateSearchString());
        }
    });

    searchQueryEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});

    stockItemsToSearch = loadUsersLastStocks();

    loadStockData(generateSearchString());

    //Real time updating
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadStockData(generateSearchString());
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 3000);
}

private ArrayList<String> loadUsersLastStocks() {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ArrayList<String> lastStocks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(MainActivity.user.get("last_stocks"));
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stockItem = jsonObject.getString("stock_item");
            lastStocks.add(stockItem);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return lastStocks;
}

private void checkForNotify() {
    for (StockItem stockItem : stockItems) {
        try {
            if (Double.parseDouble(stockItem.getBid()) > stockItem.getNotifyValue() && stockItem.getNotifyValue() > 0) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                                .setContentTitle("Remote hub")
                                .setContentText("One of stocks reached notify level");

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MarketInfo.class);

                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MarketInfo.class);

                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                0,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(151651, mBuilder.build());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

private String generateSearchString() {
    String ss = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < stockItemsToSearch.size(); i++) {
        ss += "" + stockItemsToSearch.get(i) + "";
        if (i != stockItemsToSearch.size() - 1)
            ss += "+";
    }

    return ss;
}

private void loadStockData(final String searchString) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + searchString + "&f=snpb6c");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                String responce = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                String[] sf = responce.split("\n");

                stockItems.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < sf.length; i++) {
                    String[] s = sf[i].split(",");

                    StockItem stockItem = new StockItem(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);

                    stockItems.add(stockItem);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        checkForNotify();

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) { Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR"); }
        }
    }; thread.start();
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    String uuid = db.getUserDetails().get("uid");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    try {
        for (String si : stockItemsToSearch) {
            Log.d("ITEMS", si);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("stock_item", si);
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    db.updateUsersLastStocks(jsonArray.toString(), uuid);

    MainActivity.user = db.getUserDetails();

    updateUsersLastStocks(jsonArray.toString(), uuid);
}

private void updateUsersLastStocks(final String newValue, final String uuid) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_UPDATE_LAST_STOCKS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", error.toString());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("uid", uuid);
            params.put("newLastStocks", newValue);

            return params;
        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, "d");
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<StockItem> dataset;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = v;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<StockItem> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.stock_info_row_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        View view = holder.view;

        final StockItem stockItem = dataset.get(position);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView bidTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bidTextView);
        Button deleteRowButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowButton);

        nameTextView.setText(stockItem.getNameWithFullName());
        bidTextView.setText(stockItem.getBid() + "\n" + stockItem.getChange().substring(1, stockItem.getChange().length() - 1));

        deleteRowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataset.remove(stockItem);

                timer.cancel();
                timer = new Timer();
                timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadStockData(generateSearchString());
                    }
                };

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stockItemsToSearch.remove(position);
                        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        //recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 3000);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MarketInfo.this);

                final EditText editText = new EditText(MarketInfo.this);

                editText.setWidth(300);

                editText.setHint("Notify me value");

                builder.setView(editText);

                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (editText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                int notifyValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                                if (notifyValue <= Double.parseDouble(stockItem.getBid()))
                                    throw new Exception();
                                else
                                    stockItem.setNotifyValue(notifyValue);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MarketInfo.this, "Notify value should be bigger than current bid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                builder.create().show();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Check StockItem.getNameWithFullName()

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is enforced during JSON decoding. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952237/removing-quotation-marks-in-jsonobject) question.

You can manually remove the quotes with:

`lastStocks.add(stockItem.replace("\"", ""));`